# Supply *.pc file for pkg-config

Tags: pkg-config, fedora-21

Hi I got a problem with my newly installed Fedora linux distribution. pkg-config is supposed to provide linker flags, something like `pkg-config --cflags libboost-dev`. But pkg-config cannot find most of the library packages. `pkg-config --list-all` shows that it can find only a few packages.

I searched online and learned that pkg-config finds packages by searching in the pre-defined paths for the *.pc files. However for most packages (both pre-installed and user-installed), there are no such .pc file. So the *.pc file is not generated everytime when a package installs.

1, How can I provide a .pc file for each of the packages that has already been installed?
2, How can I make sure that for each time a new package is installed, the .pc file is provided?

Comment: I'm using dnf (previously yum in Fedora) to install most of the packages.

Comment: Are you installing the `xyz-devel` packages, rather than just `xyz`? I think the development packages provide the .pc files since they also install headers - the normal packages typically do not

Comment: I tried boost, gsl, they both are used to develop c++ code, but don't have .pc files.

Comment: I mean try (for example) `sudo dnf install boost-devel` or similar

Comment: @chrisb2244, not bad, gsl-dev can be found by pkg-config, however boost-dev cannot. May I also ask what is the typical difference between a dev version and the corresponding non-dev version?

Comment: Fedora (and I think many distributions) use `-devel` to distinguish packages which contain the header files - that is, those which you would `#include` when building `c` and `c++` programs. Both the `devel` and standard packages include binaries (executable programs that do something) and libraries (which you can link binaries against - that is, they contain some set of instructions telling a program how to do something). Header files often end with `.h`, `.H`, `.hpp`, `.hxx` or similar, in contrast with source files which might end `.c`, `.C`, `.cpp`, `.cxx` etc

Comment: That means that if I have non-del versions then I cannot include the headers hence cannot use the libraries in my code? @chrisb2244

Comment: Right - see [this Fedora packaging guideline](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:Guidelines#Pkgconfig_Files_.28foo.pc.29) link for information about the concepts used at Fedora. The section immediately above also describes `-devel` packages

Answer (score 2):

The [Fedora packaging guidelines](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:Guidelines) give information about the way in which packages should be created, and the files they should contain.

The section about [`-devel` packages](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:Guidelines#Devel_Packages) is particularly relevant.

To highlight some parts

> There are some types of files which almost always belong in a `-devel` package:
>
> - Header files (foo.h), usually found in /usr/include
> - Static library files when the package does not provide any matching shared library files. See [Packaging:Guidelines#Packaging_Static_Libraries](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:Guidelines#Packaging_Static_Libraries) for more information about this scenario.
> - Unversioned shared system library files, when a matching versioned shared system library file is also present.

In the next section, regarding [Pkgconfig Files](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:Guidelines#Pkgconfig_Files_.28foo.pc.29), the page informs the reader that

> The placement of pkgconfig(.pc) files depends on their usecase. Since they are almost always used for development purposes, they should be placed in a -devel package.
>
> A reasonable exception is when the main package itself is a development tool not installed in a user runtime, e.g. gcc or gdb.

As a result, in order to get either header files to `#include`, or `.pc` files to tell you compiler flags, you will need the `xyz-devel` package, where `xyz` is the name of the standard package.

A useful website to find the appropriate names of packages to install, if you can't/don't want to guess them, is the [Fedora Packages search page](https://apps.fedoraproject.org/packages/).